# Como hacer que se respete el tamaño de un contenedor en HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo lo siguiente

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bg-logo {
  background: #4a4045;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 14px 0 0 50px;
}

#opciones {
  background: #6b6063;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ea1c2c;
}

.active {
  background-color: #6b6063;
}

button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #3a7999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #3a7999;
}

#fondo {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('../Imagenes/fondo.png');
}

table {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>2019</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="bg-logo">
      <img src="Imagenes/Logotipo.png">
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th rowSpan="2">TERRITORIO</th>
        <th rowSpan="2">ESQUEMA</th>
        <th colspan="2">2016</th>
        <th colspan="2">2017</th>
        <th colspan="2">2018</th>
        <th colspan="2">2019</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 16-17</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 17-18</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var Abs 18-19</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 18-19</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Mi  tiene width: 900px pero, la tabla lo sobrepasa, saben como puedo ajustar la tabla al tamaño del

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Muchas veces el % no lo respeta el navegador, prueba poniendo px en lugar de % y dale un margin: auto; para centrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probé tu código cambiando el tamaño de las letras de la tabla. Lo dejé así.

```
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sucede es que el tamaño de las letras de la table toman el valor por defecto del navegador si tu no especificas el que quieres. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

El total de información que presenta la tabla en la cabecera que es mas de 900px esta superando el ancho de la clase .contenedor.

Lo que hice fue encerrrar a la tabla dentro de un div y agregarle style="overflow:auto; width: 950px".

Quizá eso te sirva

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bg-logo {
  background: #4a4045;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 14px 0 0 50px;
  width:900px
}

#opciones {
  background: #6b6063;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ea1c2c;
}

.active {
  background-color: #6b6063;
}

button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #3a7999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #3a7999;
}

#fondo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('../Imagenes/fondo.png');
}

table {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>2019</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="bg-logo">
      <img src="Imagenes/Logotipo.png">
    </div>
<div style="overflow:auto; width: 950px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th rowSpan="2">TERRITORIO</th>
        <th rowSpan="2">ESQUEMA</th>
        <th colspan="2">2016</th>
        <th colspan="2">2017</th>
        <th colspan="2">2018</th>
        <th colspan="2">2019</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 16-17</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 17-18</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var Abs 18-19</th>
        <th colspan="2">Var % 18-19</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>MONTO</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esto debería funcionar:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

El problema es que el contenido de tu tabla es muy grande para 900px. Prueba como se ve cambiando el **width: 900px;** de tu contenedor por **min-width: 900px;** y veráz como se acomoda. Ya después revisa tus paddings y tamaño de fuente, son muy grandes para el poco espacio que tienes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en tu css, debería quedar así

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

el 100% se refiere a que ocupara todo el ancho disponible, y quien marca este limite es el ancho del contenedor (div)

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar